# How i draw and handle Two crop rect in single imageView?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, crop

[image]

I try to handle Two crop inside single imageview but fail to handle both.

I would like to create a new UIImage by cropping the image inside a UIImageView. For example in the below pic

Comment: You didn't add the pic :)

Comment: what do you mean by "Two crop"?

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: @ShahiM its two crop in same imageview and cant calculate draw and translation